# Parsing Large Chunks of HTML with re.findall()

Tags: python, regex, urllib2

I have a project that I am working on at home that uses the rottentomatoes API to gather movies currently in theaters. It then gathers all images on those movies' imdb page. The issue I am having trouble with is the gathering of the images.. The goal here is to get this code to run under 8 seconds, but the regex command and am running is taking forever! Currently I am using a regular expression:

```
re.findall('<img.*?>', str(line))
```

where line is a chunk of HTML

Does anyone have a better regex expression that they can think of (perhaps more refined?) All comments welcome!!

Full code below and attached.

```
import json, re, pprint, time
from urllib2 import urlopen

def get_image(url):

    total  = 0
    page   = urlopen(url).readlines()

    for line in page:

        hit   = re.findall('<img.*?>', str(line))
        total += len(hit)
    # print('{0} Images total: {1}'.format(url, total))
    return total


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    json_list = list()
    url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/in_theaters.json?apikey=<apikey>"
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())

    for i in data["movies"]:
        json_dict = dict()
        json_dict["Title"] = str(i['title'])
        json_dict["url"] = str("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt" + i['alternate_ids']['imdb'])
        json_dict["imdb_id"] = str(i['alternate_ids']['imdb'])
        json_dict["count"] = get_image(str(json_dict["url"]) )
        json_list.append(json_dict)
    end = time.time()
    pprint.pprint(json_list)
    runtime =  end - start
    print "Program runtime: " + str(runtime)
```

Comment: Have you considered using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: [*sigh*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2581969)

Comment: I would like to have it run using python2.7 std libs. No external dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although I know using regex to search for img tags in HTML is not
>   ideal, here is the approached I ended up going with. By threading I
>   was able to get the runtime to anywhere from 2-12 seconds depending on
>   your connection:

```
#No shebang line, please run in Linux shell % python img_count.py

#Python libs
import threading, urllib2, re
import Queue, json, time, pprint

#Global lists 
JSON_LIST = list()
URLS = list()

def get_movies():
    url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/in_theaters.json?apikey=    <apikey>"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())    
    return data


def get_imgs(html):
    total = 0
    # This next line is not ideal. Would much rather use a lib such as Beautiful Soup for this
    total += len(re.findall(r"<img[^>]*>", html)) 
    return total


def read_url(url, queue):
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    queue.put(data)


def fetch_urls():
    result = Queue.Queue()
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=read_url, args = (url,result)) for url in URLS]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    movies = get_movies()
    for movie in movies["movies"]:
        url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt" + movie['alternate_ids']['imdb']
        URLS.append(url)    
    queue = fetch_urls()
    while movies["movies"]:
        movie = movies["movies"].pop()
        job = queue.get()
        total = get_imgs(job)    
        json_dict = {
                "title": movie['title'],
                "url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt" + movie['alternate_ids']['imdb'],
                "imdb_id": movie['alternate_ids']['imdb'],
                "count": total 
                } 
        JSON_LIST.append(json_dict)      
    pprint.pprint(JSON_LIST)
    end = time.time()
    print "\n"
    print "Elapsed Time (seconds):", end - start
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse HTML with regular expressions. If you can only use standard libraries for Python 2, use HTMLParser:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
class ImgFinder(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'img':
            print 'found img tag, src=', dict(attrs)['src']

parser = ImgFinder()
parser.feed(... HTML source ...)
```

Comment: Tried this already.... This does not find nested img tags.... and what about img tags generated by javascript? No go.

Comment: @DirkDigler *no* parsing schema will be able to parse img tags generated by javascript - because they are simply not in the page source.  They only exist in the DOM once a javascript engine runs whatever scripts need to be run.

Comment: @roippi Javascript CAN be in page source.... Run this code and tell me if you see Javascript in stdout:                                      page= urlopen("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2978462").readlines()
for line in page:
    if line:
        print line

Comment: How would someone handle JS in HTML source that looks like this: onclick="(new Image()).src='/rg/help/footer/images/b.gif?link=/help/';"

Comment: Of course the raw javascript `<script>` appears in the source, any alterations to the DOM *by* that javascript will not occur until it actually gets run by a js engine.  To parse that you would need to visit the page with a headless browser (like `selenium`), execute the js on the page with `PhantomJS`, click the element, and *then* parse the page source.

Comment: @roippi, that makes sense. But we still haven't answered the question of nested IMG tags. Check out this fiddle -http://pythonfiddle.com/html-parser-test/ Then view page source source:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1065073/ and do a simple find for "<img".... 52 results! That fiddle script above returns 3 imgs found, what am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

While you certainly should listen to the general wisdom that it's a bad idea to use regex to parse html (you *really should* use an html parser) there is a point to be made about the efficiency of your regex.

Compare these two:

```
>>> timeit('import re; re.findall("<img.*?>", \'blah blah blah <img src="http://www.example.org/test.jpg"> blah blah blah <img src="http://wwww.example.org/test2.jpg"> blah blah blah\')')
3.366645097732544
>>> timeit('import re; re.findall("<img[^>]*>", \'blah blah blah <img src="http://www.example.org/test.jpg"> blah blah blah <img src="http://wwww.example.org/test2.jpg"> blah blah blah\')')
2.328295946121216
```

You can see that the latter regex, which is equivalent, is actually noticeably faster.  That's because it doesn't require backtracking. See this great blog post http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance for an explanation of why that is.

Comment: I think `.*?>` is a repetitive two step process. Checking if the character is `>`, if not then consume 1 character (repeats over and over). `[^>]*` immediately find the next `>`, then consume match position up to here. But it can be played with to make it backtrack from `>` if the next character is not `>`. This is useful if you need to search backwards from a starting point where things overlap and no real hard anchors can be used.

Comment: Thank you FatalError: "<img[^>]*>" Shaved a few seconds off of the runtime. And yes, I agree with you that regex is not the right way to go but I want this to run out of the box with python 2.x so tools like BeautifulSoup or Mechanize are out of the question....